# How to set the status of parent build by rebuilding only one child job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I have a use case where, a trigger (t1) triggers 2 jobs (j1, j2). If one of the job failed then the trigger status is set failed. There are some infrastructure issues in our app, if do the rebuild j2 might pass.
Now how can I set the set the status of trigger by only rebuilding the errored jobs.

Answer (score 0):

With https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin you solve that problem.
You can promote job if there have a certain status. 
And Downstream jobs only run if a certain promotion is given.